# SFMC Leads By Day

Tags: marketing-cloud, datorama

I'm simply trying to set up a report in Datorama that details the leads that come into our Salesforce by day (later want to add extra dimensions like lead source, but for now just this) - through the report connector.

I think I've got it set up correctly.

Lead_ID -> Lead Key |
Lead_Source -> Lead Source |
Parsed Date [Create_Date] -> Lead Creation Date |
Parsed Date [Create_Date] -> Lead Modified Date |
Lead_ID -> Lead Count CRM (just a custom COUNT) |

That seems to run, but no matter the date range I select in my report, it doesn't change the figures. I tried looking into a custom measurement that was COUNTDISTINCT([Lead_Key]) but that didn't get anywhere.

Where am I going wrong, help appreciated!